# best way to extract a file from a zip file and put it back into the zip file after editing

Tags: shell

I am wondering if anyone can help me with a shell script to do the following job:

Extract a file from a zip file and put it back in after some editing, e.g. using `sed` to do some replacement.

I want to avoid extracting all contents of the zip file into a temporary folder. It could be possible that the zip file contains files with the same name as the one I want to replace with editing. In such case, I want to specify the full path of such file inside the zip file.

Is there any good way to do this task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Extract a file from a zip file:

   unzip file.zip file/you/want/to/extract/the_file.txt
2. Modify the_file.txt
3. Put it back:

   zip file.zip file/you/want/to/extract/the_file.txt

That should get you started.

Comment: +1 and thanks! The first unzip does not actually remove the file from the zip file. And the second zip actually overwrite the original content. Correct? Is there a way in the first step to remove (only) the target file from the zip file?

Comment: Yes it does not remove the file from the zip file. To remove the file from the zip file you'll have to do a separate step: zip -d file.zip file/to/delete.txt, I looked this up in the zip man page, the -d or --delete option.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any zip files handy to test with. but continuing on with holygeek's solution, I don't think you have to even save it to disk, but run it thru some pipes.

```
unzip -p file.zip /path/2/your/file.txt \
| sed 's/x/y/g' \
| zip file.zip /path/2/your/file.txt -
```

Note the last '-' is critical, it tells zip to read its data from stdin.

This is from the zip -h2 (full help),  under example streams.

Comment: my `zip -h2` only specifies it will zip stdin, and in my case it creates an entry named "-" within the zip file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710341/linux-zip-command-add-a-file-with-different-name shows how to rename.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fuse-zip to mount the zip file to a location and edit the file.
look at http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/

```
fuse-zip my.zip /tmp_location
edit some file (sed ...)
fusermount -u /tmp_location
```

Comment: User was looking for a shell script. You can't see it, but there's a deleted post where someone already suggested FUSE and OP said it was not an option.

Comment: it's very simple to mount the file in a script do the changes and unmount it.

Comment: It's also very simple to do what the other answers do. Even simpler, in fact. And simplicity was not the point, anyway; as I said, the OP said FUSE was simply not an option. His words, "I don't have the luxury to install FUSE"

Comment: maybe this will help someone else with similar problems