# Linux zip command: add a file with different name

Tags: linux, command, zip, rename

I´d like to add a file in a zip file, with a different name, and avoiding the creation of a new file with the desired name.

For example, I´d like to add the file `myfile.txt` to a zip, but renaming it to `myfile2.txt`.

Comment: Don't understand why is it offtopic

Comment: I also vote that this is not offtopic here.  `zip` is a standard development tool to bundle releases.  And changing the name of distributed files when bundeling them within a `Makefile` can be considered a very common practice.  Hence if there is a solution which do not include copies into temporary files/directories this is a very welcome idiom to use to solve a  pretty common programming task.

Comment: Voting to leave closed as a [work request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason).

Comment: It seems quite arbitrary that this was closed as off-topic. There are plenty of questions about how to use the zip command on SO that haven't been closed as off-topic. I'm voting to reopen. Judging from all the upvotes, this is a good and useful question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use zipnote which should come with the zip package.

First build the zip archive with the myfile.txt file:

```
zip archive.zip myfile.txt
```

Then rename myfile.txt inside the zip archive with:

```
printf "@ myfile.txt\n@=myfile2.txt\n" | zipnote -w archive.zip
```

(Thanks to [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648658/jens) for suggesting `printf` instead of `echo -e`.)

A short explanation of `"@ myfile.txt\n@=myfile2.txt\n"`:

From `zipnote -h`: "@ name" can be followed by an "@=newname" line to change the name

And `\n` separates the two commands.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `echo -e` is an unportable SysVism. I'd use `printf "@ myfile.txt\n@=myfile2.txt\n" | ...`.

Comment: Good point. Modified my answer.

Comment: I don't know why but I can make it work. See my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974139/how-to-use-zipnote-command

Comment: Note: if you want to do multiple filename changes, you need to follow each chunk by `@ (comment above this line)\n`

Comment: >The temporary file format is rather specific and zipnote is rather picky about it.  It should be easier to change file names in a script. Does not yet support large (> 2 GB) or split archives.

Comment: how about changing a directory name?

Comment: @Freedom Rather late, but I found that using relative paths like `"@ myDir/file.txt\n@=anotherDir/file.txt\n"` works. Not entirely sure if this is portable, although checking a random ZIP file I made without using the `zip` command revealed comments of the type `"@ path/to/file.ext"`.

Comment: zip 3.1 appears to be pretty uncommon (the one in Debian/Ubuntu is 3.0, and yes, it's 11 years old)...

Comment: @mkrnr    @Jens This is working for normal filenames but it's not working for unicode chars like `Ю`. I need to replace that with `_` because some zip program on server(that i can't control) is converting all `_` to `Ю` after compressing(as shown in bash with `zipinfo -1 file.zip` locally) or in GUI showing as  009E in a box like █  (yes, it's \u009e)