# How to use zipnote command?

Tags: linux, zip

I'm trying to use `zipnote` to rename files in an zip archive but I can't figure out how to use it properly. There's already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710341/linux-zip-command-add-a-file-with-different-name) but it doesn't work for some reason.

When I try to use:

```
printf "@ myfile.txt\n@=myfile2.txt\n" | zipnote -w archive.zip
```

I just says:

```
zipnote error: Bad file descriptor
zipnote error: Temporary file failure (ziMZslgn)
```

This throws exactly the same error message which is weird to me:

```
zipnote test.zip > a.txt
zipnote -w test.zip < a.txt
```

I'm running OS X 10.9 but the manual page doesn't mention any difference to the standard linux `zipnote`.

edit: On Debian 6.0 it returns:

```
zipnote error: Bad file descriptor
*** Error in `zipnote': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x0000000000d962e0 ***
zipnote error: Temporary file failure (ziw8B942)
*** Error in `zipnote': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000d962e0 ***
```

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you found a workaround other than installing zip 3.1? For me this works on Linux but not on macOS (using zip 3.0 on both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [zip 3.1 beta](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/problems-with-zipnote-writing-to-files-4175502552/)

Comment: Well, if this is a bug, there not much to answer. A link to the bug report would be nice though.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/problems-with-zipnote-writing-to-files-4175502552/