# Zipping a file with a new path

Tags: perl, zip

I have the following directory tree:

```
mydir/
mydir/bbb/
mydir/bbb/ccc/
mydir/bbb/ccc/myfile.txt
```

The file zips as follows:

```
bbb\ccc\myfile.txt
```

I want it to appear as

```
\ddd\myfile.txt
```

The command-line `zip` utility does not seem to have option. Is there another way, perhaps using Perl. I'm using a unix system.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you use if `zip` won't let you rename as part of the zipping process (and I don't know that it does). This is a `zip` tool question. Does it let you map one path to another or do you need to make the actual directory (or symlink) that has the name you want first.

Comment: @ikegami That's still a "tooling" question though. The tool may be a direct perl zip module though. Either zip lets you do it and the tooling is the question or it doesn't. The tooling question is secondary though. And I did mention it.

Comment: @ikegami When I said "a `zip` tool question" I didn't mean the `zip` binary. I meant "whatever you use to create the archive" (I shouldn't have used backticks there). So my point was that the question is two parts. First, does zip (the library/etc.) let you manually specify the name. Second, (and only if the answer to the first part is "yes") does any available zipping tool/binding/library allow you to do that. In either case, ultimately, the question of what you use doesn't matter (beyond whether it exposes the right knobs).

Comment: It looks like I'm alone not understanding what you mean by the text beneath *"I have a file as such"*. Are you saying you have a file `mydir\bbb\ccc\myfile.txt`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux zip command: add a file with different name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710341/linux-zip-command-add-a-file-with-different-name)

Comment: @Etan Reisner, Those two questions are the same thing. If the library can do it, then there is a tool that can do it given that you consider the library to be a tool.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then it looks like the [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Zip) module will do what you need.

Once you have created an archive, you can use `addFile` to add an archive member whose path is different from the source. Like this

```
$zip->addFile( {
  filename => 'mydir\bbb\ccc\myfile.txt',
  zipName  => 'ddd\myfile.txt',
} );
```

For instance, this program creates a zip archive and adds the contents of the current script (defined by `$0`) as a member called `ddd\current.pl`. The archive is then written to a file called `current.zip`. If you open that file using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or similar then you will see `ddd\current.pl`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;

$zip->addFile( {
  filename => $0,
  zipName  => 'ddd\current.pl',
} );

$zip->writeToFileNamed('current.zip');
```

Comment: Might make sense to add this to the ticket being marked as duplicate so that they are in the same place.